Show that there is no simple group of order 351
I want to show that there is no simple group of order $351 = 3^3 \cdot 13$.
Let $G$ be a group. of order 351. Using Sylow III, I found that $n_3 \in \{1,13\}, \quad n_{13}\in \{1,27\}$. Let us suppose that $G$ is simple. Then $n_3 = 13,\quad n_{13} = 27$. My main concern is regarding my argument below as to why this cannot be possible. My argument: The Sylow 13-subgroups are cyclic (as of prime order), and so the number of elements of order 13 is equal to $27(13-1) = 324$. We have 13 Sylow 3-subgroups, so just considering one of them gives us an additional 27 elements. Since we have 13 Sylow 3-subgroups, these cannot all be identical, since otherwise we would just have 1 Sylow 3-subgroup. Putting this together, this tells us that $|G| > 324 + 27 = 351$, which is a contradiction. Hence $G$ cannot be simple. Is the argument concerning counting elements sensible?
NOTE:
I know that the elements of Sylow 3-subgroups cannot lie in any of the Sylow 13-subgroups, since by Lagrange's Theorem this would imply 3 divides 13.

Of course, no simple (or non-solvable) group of order $351$ exists for two other reasons (namely, the Feit-Thompson theorem since $351$ is odd and Burnside's $p^a q^b$ theorem since $351$ is of the form $p^a q^b$).

Yes your counting argument is correct.

https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info

Slightly simpler: Do don't need to assume anything on $n_3$. Your counting leaves exactly 27 elements outside Sylow 13-subgroups. So there can only be one Sylow 3-subgroup.
